# Xcode 6 GM Seed error - NSMachError Domain 5

Tags: ios8, xcode6gm

[image: Following error is displayed while trying to run the build, app has today widget extension.]
Screen shot of error is attached.

Answer (score 2):

I Encountered the same problem this helped men.
I check my TodayViewController and widget Story board was not added in target . I added them im target and it solved my problem. May be it can help.

Answer (score 1):

-Check your TodayViewController.m has target membership with extension target in right side bar.
In my case, it worked.